# When I want to process DocumentTermMatrix type dataset by using R function apply , I got the error

Tags: r

Below is my DTM type data set:

> View(sms_dtm_freq_train)
>   sms_dtm_freq_train[["dimnames"]]
>   $`Docs`
>      [1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "5"    "6"    "7"    "8"    "9"    "10"   "11"   "12"   "13"   "14"
>     [15] "15"   "16"   "17"   "18"   "19"   "20"   "21"   "22"   "23"   "24"   "25"   "26"   "27"   "28"
>     [29] "29"   "30"   "31"   "32"   "33"   "34"   "35"   "36"   "37"   "38"   "39"   "40"   "41"   "42"
>     [43] "43"   "44"   "45"   "46"   "47"   "48"   "49"   "50"   "51"   "52"   "53"   "54"   "55"   "56"
>     [57] "57"   "58"   "59"   "60"   "61"   "62"   "63"   "64"   "65"   "66"   "67"   "68"   "69"   "70"
>     [71] "71"   "72"   "73"   "74"   "75"   "76"   "77"   "78"   "79"   "80"   "81"   "82"   "83"   "84"
>     [85] "85"   "86"   "87"   "88"   "89"   "90"   "91"   "92"   "93"   "94"   "95"   "96"   "97"   "98"
>     [99] "99"   "100"  "101"  "102"  "103"  "104"  "105"  "106"  "107"  "108"  "109"  "110"  "111"  "112" 
>    ..........
>    [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 4057 entries ]

$Terms
   [1] "â£wk"          "â€¦"           "â€“"           "abiola"        "abl"           "abt"
   [7] "accept"        "access"        "account"       "across"        "activ"         "actual"
  [13] "add"           "address"       "admir"         "adult"         "advanc"        "aft"
  [19] "afternoon"     "aftr"          "age"           "ago"           "ahead"         "aight"
  [25] "aint"          "air"           "aiyah"         "alex"          "almost"        "alon"
  [31] "alreadi"       "alright"       "alrit"         "also"          "alway"         "amp"
  [37] "angri"         "announc"       "anoth"         "answer"        "anybodi"       "anymor"
  [43] "anyon"         "anyth"         "anytim"        "anyway"        "apart"         "app"
  [49] "appli"         "appoint"       "appreci"       "april"         "ard"           "area"
  [55] "argument"      "arm"           "around"        "arrang"        "arrest"        "arriv"
  [61] "asap"          "ask"           "askd"          "asleep"        "ass"           "attempt"
  [67] "auction"       "avail"         "ave"           "avoid"         "await"         "award"
  [73] "away"          "awesom"        "babe"          "babi"          "back"          "bad"
  [79] "bag"           "bak"           "balanc"        "bank"          "bare"          "bath"
  [85] "batteri"       "bcoz"          "bcum"          "bday"          "beauti"        "becom"
  [91] "bed"           "bedroom"       "begin"         "believ"        "belli"         "best"
  [97] "better"        "bid"           "big"           "bill"          "bird"          "birthday"
..............

[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 1057 entries ]

When i run:

> sms_train <- apply(sms_dtm_freq_train, MARGIN = 2, convert_counts)

I got the error messages below:

Error in apply(sms_dtm_freq_train, MARGIN = 2, convert_counts) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length

I type the same codes as the text book "Machine Learning with R" 's , but i got the errors.
I am very confused.
Anyone can help me solve this problem ?
Thanks!

Comment: can you `dput` your objects for reproducibility please. also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: try `apply(as.data.frame(sms_dtm_freq_train), MARGIN = 2, convert_counts)` or `apply(as.matrix(sms_dtm_freq_train), MARGIN = 2, convert_counts)`. The problem seems to be the data structure of `sms_dtm_fre_train`. `dim(sms_dtm_freq_train)` should output the number of rows and columns.